# How to decide which radio button to click

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create variables at the top of my script so that users can manipulate it's values without needing to go down into the code. E.g.

```
# Airports
FROM = "Leeds Bradford"
TO = "Antalya"

...//Later in code

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("departure-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys(FROM)

depart_from = driver.find_element_by_id("destination-airport-input")
depart_from.clear()
depart_from.send_keys(TO)
```

One thing I can't seem to get my head around is where a user may have a choice between selecting one radio button or the other. At the moment it's rigid where I say click this type of radio button.

```
return_flight = driver.find_element_by_id('return-flight-selector').click()
```

But I want the user to decide which radio button to select between the above and below:

```
one_flight = driver.find_element_by_id('oneway-flight-selector').click()
```

Is there a way I can do this? I want to assign a number to a radio button, so that all the user needs to do is change a number to get either one or the other? Like for example having a variable call `FLIGHT_TYPE = ?` ? is either "0" meaning select the `return_flight` radio button, or "1" meaning select the `one_flight` radio button.

Comment: Surely just use `if/elif` statements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure make a boolean variable and call it, for instance, `ONE_WAY`. Then, depending on it's value decide which item to click:

```
ONE_WAY = True

if ONE_WAY: 
    driver.find_element_by_id('oneway-flight-selector').click()
else:
    driver.find_element_by_id('return-flight-selector').click()
```

Comment: Can tell long day at work when can't think of a simple if statement anymore. I was over complicating it in my head. Did you receive my comment anyway on that custom_clickable function where it wasn't working for some strange reason?

Comment: @BruceyBandit yeah, have it on my TODO list, will return to that later, thanks. Hope this one helps.

Comment: It does help, sorry forthe simple question. Just couldn't think about it and i was thinking for about 20 minutes (whilst coding) before deciding to post it on SO